# Is it possible to make a timing function which can call a function as a parameter then run and time it?

Tags: c++

So I have an assignment in which my code must test the run time of a function repeatedly to get an average. The assignment has several sections in which this must be done.

I have working code, but I would like to be able to call the timing function using some function as a parameter...then have it run that function a certain number of repetitions, and afterward return the result.

(This is not a requirement for the assignment. I just like to go beyond what is required and do something interesting and unique whenever possible.)

It would be nice to be able to call the function in a fashion like:

```
timingRoutine(functionName);
```

or

```
timingRoutine(repetitions, functionName);
```

Any suggestions or ideas??? Is this even possible?

Here's the code I have which already works for timing a countLastName function in the assignment. I'm not particularly proud of it:

```
const int TIMING_REPETITIONS = 100000;
clock_t startTime = clock();
for(int i = 0; i < TIMING_REPETITIONS; i++) {
    countLastName("Lastname", peopleArray, size);
}
clock_t endTime = clock();
double testResult = static_cast<double>(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / TIMING_REPETITIONS;
```

Comment: You can use a pointer to the function you need to time.

Answer (score 3):

You can arrange a generic function like this:

```
 #include <functional>

double test(std::function<void()> f)
{
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    f();
    clock_t endTime = clock();
    return static_cast<double>(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

then you can pass a function to it:

```
void somefunction()
{
    const int TIMING_REPETITIONS = 100000;
    for(int i = 0; i < TIMING_REPETITIONS; i++) {
        countLastName("Lastname", peopleArray, size);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    std::cout << test(somefunction) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

or a lambda

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto f = [=]()
    {
        const int TIMING_REPETITIONS = 100000;
        for(int i = 0; i < TIMING_REPETITIONS; i++) {
            countLastName("Lastname", peopleArray, size);
        }
    };

    std::cout << test(f) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Here is one way (of many):

```
double time_it(std::function<void()> fn, int repetitions)
{
    clock_t startTime = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
        fn();
    }
    clock_t endTime = clock();
    return static_cast<double>(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / repetitions;
}
```

Example use:

```
// With a function pointer:
void foo() { /* Do something... */ }
double fooTime = time_it(foo, 1000);

// With a lambda function:
double lastNameTime = time_it([&]() { countLastName("Lastname", peopleArray, size); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C with the usage of function pointers. You can still do this in C++, but I think the standard way of doing it now is to have std::function in there and call it. In your time function, simply sandwich the input function between your timing method and it'd work. More info on std::function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function